# Another static solution of the Friedmann equations - interpretation of $p=-\rho c^2$

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, dark-energy, cosmological-constant, scale-invariance

Looking for solutions of the Friedmann equations

$$(\frac{\dot a}{a})^2+\frac{kc^2}{a^2} = \frac{8 \pi G \rho+\Lambda c^2}{3}, \tag{1}$$

$$\frac{\ddot a}{a} = \frac{-4 \pi G}{3} (\rho + \frac{3p}{c^2}) +\frac{\Lambda c^2}{3}. \tag{2}$$

There seems to be this possibility

with $\Lambda = 0$, $k=0$, constant $H$, and $a=e^{Ht}$, the equations reduce to

$$3H^2 = 8 \pi G \rho, \tag{3}$$

$$3H^2 = -4 \pi G(\rho + \frac{3p}{c^2}), \tag{4}$$

leading to the solution

$$\rho = \frac{3H^2}{8 \pi G}, \tag{5}$$

$$p = - \rho c^2. \tag{6}$$

A nice, simple solution with scaling symmetry and time symmetry.  If the expansion happens to all length scales including the observer as in [Cosmology - an expansion of all length scales](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/620794/)  then the solution is an apparently static universe (but with a redshift as described in the link) and a universe always at critical density.

But the question is, what is the best interpretation of $p = - \rho c^2$ in a universe with $\Lambda = 0$?  One idea is that explosive events in the universe e.g. from the nuclei of galaxies provide the negative pressure  - is there any other way to interpret this?

Comment: 1. In that answer, I mentioned that "Schrödinger in 1918 proposed that the Einstein’s static universe can be obtained from the Einstein field equations without a positive cosmological constant if a negative-pressure term was added to the stress-energy tensor on the right-hand side of the Einstein field equations! But this is controversial since this proposal is equivalent to introducing a cosmological constant at the level of the action of the theory."

Comment: And after that, I mentioned "After this proposal, Einstein stated that he, in this way, indeed discovered that the cosmological constant is able to account theoretically for the existence of a finite mean density in a static universe." So, the answer by @OON is quite reasonable (as OON wrote: a contribution to $T_{\mu\nu}$ that looks like an ideal fluid with $w=\frac{p}{\rho}=-1$). No need for emphasizing, they are completely (?) equivalent, as well understood by Einstein.

Comment: In conclusion, we discussed a solution with $\Lambda =0$ and $k=0$ (spatially flat) and a negative-pressure component in $T^{\mu \nu}$, which is equivalent to a cosmological model with $\Lambda >0$ and $k=0$. This is exactly the (spatially) de Sitter model which is a special case of Lemaitre model. But, since this model assumes the matter radiation/matter densities are zero is not a realistic model. However, it's an interesting toy model. (I also upvoted the @OON answer for making it more clear)

Comment: 2. It would be, perhaps, more interesting to consider the case with $\Lambda=0$ but a non-zero $k$. Regarding this, we can have an static universe if we set $\rho+3p=0$ and $k=\frac{{8\pi\rho{a^2}}}{3}$. But, again, the problem is what is the negative-pressure component? Again, you will end up with a cosmological constant interpretation.

Comment: 3. Regarding the first two (Friedmann) equations in your post: the case with $\Lambda=0$ and $k=0$ and a negative-pressure term could not be static since (I think) it cannot satisfies the static condition, i.e., $\ddot a= \dot a=0$. However the Hubble parameter is a constant but $a$ grows exponentially (I haven't read that link in your post yet. My time is very limited). But, the case with $\Lambda=0$ and $k>0$ and a negative-pressure could be static since it satisfies $\ddot a= \dot a=0$, as mentioned be Weinberg in his book (see my previous answer and the references therein, please)

Comment: 4. And about your final question (an interpretation without incorporating a cosmological constant, dark energy etc): It's hard to answer your question. Evidently, a negative-pressure term is mathematically equivalent to a positive cosmological constant. But, the underlying physics in these two case is surely different. Here is the Einstein's response: In terms of the Newtonian theory. . . a modification of the theory is required such that “empty space” takes the role of gravitating negative masses which are distributed all over the interstellar space”. See <arxiv.org/abs/1701.07261>

Comment: Finally, the model that you are curious about ($\Lambda=0$ and $k=0$, but without a pressure term) has been considered in this (open access) short paper <https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1076193/> by Einstein and de Sitter. This may be useful.

Comment: Thankyou for the comments, it'll take time to look at them.  Regarding the comments starting "In conclusion" and "3." By joining the solution shown to the link (hope you'll look at that), a solution is found where the universe is apparently static even without $ \ddot a= \dot a=0 $ and without a zero matter density...

Comment: @ SG8 Thanks, been looking at your other post... Do you think there can be a valid De-sitter type expansion with constant $H$ that is apparently static even without $\ddot a= \dot a=0$, using the type of expansion in the link, where the observer expands as well?  If so it might suit our universe, it would be a universe always at critical density (no co-incidence problem) and no need for zero matter density.  But what would the best interpretation be of  $p=-\rho c^2$ should it be part of $T _{\mu\nu}$ ?  If so what would it represent?

Answer (score 1):

The solution you consider is well-known de Sitter space. What you've got is the cosmological constant interpreted not as a separate $\Lambda$-term but as a contribution to $T_{\mu\nu}$ that looks like an ideal fluid with $w=\frac{p}{\rho}=-1$ (I'll use $c=1$). Note that the stress-energy tensor for the ideal fluid looks like,
\begin{equation}
T_{\mu\nu}=(p+\rho)u_\mu u_\nu -p g_{\mu\nu}\underset{w=-1}{=} \rho g_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
This means that there's no velocity field for such a fluid and if no other matter is present $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$ enforces $\rho=const$. If you compare such a $T_{\mu\nu}$ with the $\Lambda$-term in the Einstein equation then you will see that they are completely equivalent.

The cosmological constant is the best current explanation for the Dark Energy and I will refer you to the alternative Dark Energy models for the stuff that can approximately imitate this (e.g. "quintessence" which is simply a scalar field in the slow roll regime).

Comment: Thanks.  The solution trys, by joining to the ideas in the link, to find a De Sitter universe that appears static, even without $\ddot a= \dot a=0$ and also has positive matter density.  It's interesting that you mention that the cosmological constant can be interpreted as a contribution to $T_{\mu \nu}$

Comment: @ OON Is there any known interpretation of a contribution to $T_{\mu \nu}$ that has negative $\omega$?  Not sure about this but here are examples: is negative pressure a collapse, or is it an explosion, or does antimatter have that property - is there anything at all within known physics that has negative $\omega$  - so we wouldn't need $\Lambda$ (or the unexplained dark energy)?

Comment: ...p.s. or could a gravitational constant $G$ that increased with the increasing scale-factor of the universe have that property?