# Where can I find the latest Cosmological Parameters derived from SNe Ia magnitudes?

Tags: cosmology, supernova

I'm investigating the current crisis in Cosmology.  I saw Dr. Becky quote the Hubble Constant, $H_0$, from Supernovae (SNe Ia) as 74.03.  I'd like to punch the latest figures into my models.  Does anyone know where I can find a recent paper on the current state of the Cosmological Parameters derived from SNe Ia as I'm still using the values from the 1998 paper.

In particular, I'm looking for the value for the matter density, $\Omega_M$, that I can use with this value for $H_0$ in modelling luminous distances.

Comment: Have a look at the review [In the Realm of the Hubble tension — a Review of Solutions](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.01183).

Comment: @A.V.S.   Thanks.  I also found this https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/ab1422/pdf which appears to be the source for the often quoted value of 74.03.

Answer (score 0):

[Planck](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06209) 2018, page 15 has many cosmological parameters, however the Hubble constant  differs from local measurements  [Riess](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.03624), 2020 and Riess [2019](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.07603)

You might also want to look at [Betoule](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4064) that is more specifically about parameters from supernovae.

Comment: I read the paper by Riess, but I didn't see any of the density parameters.  Did you find them anywhere?

Comment: The Betroule report does include the density parameters, but has an $H_0$ of $70.5$, so I don't see how it could be related to Riess's value of 74.02.

Comment: @Gluon Soup  Riess wanted to determine $H_0$ by the local method but doesn't find $\Omega_M$ .  ($H_0$ from BAO and Concordance model gives significantly lower, that's the crisis).  Planck measured $\Omega_Mh^2$ accurately and got 0.143, so can be used with the favourite $h$ to find $\Omega_M$...

Comment: @Gluon Soup  P.S.  The crisis is interesting as it might lead to new physics.  For a personal solution, that unfortunately seems impossible to publish, please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/620794/cosmology-an-expansion-of-all-length-scales or https://vixra.org/pdf/2006.0209v1.pdf  the theory accounts for why $\Omega_M$ is between 0.25 and 0.333 (depending on the type of investigation) and has a solution to the Hubble tension.  All the best