# Is a scalar obtained by metric contraction invariant under Weyl transformation?

Tags: metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, conformal-field-theory

Under a Weyl transformation $g_{\mu\nu}(x)\rightarrow e^{2\omega(x)}g_{\mu\nu}(x)$

So a scalar $X_\mu X^{\mu}$ should transform as following:
$$X_\mu X^{\mu}=g_{\mu\nu}X^\nu X^{\mu}\rightarrow e^{2\omega(x)}g_{\mu\nu}X^\nu X^{\mu}$$
$$=e^{2\omega(x)}X_\mu X^{\mu}$$
where $X^{\mu}$ is a $(1,0)$ tensor on spacetime whose coordinate is given by $x^\alpha$

The above calculation indicates the above-constructed scalar doesn't remain invariant under a Weyl transformation. Is it correct?

Comment: It all depends on the conformal weight attached to the tensor $X^{\mu}$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_transformation

Comment: Is your transformation global?  If so and if the conformal weight of a quantity is the number of length dimensions in it, then there is rescaling symmetry and everything is invariant https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/620794/cosmology-an-expansion-of-all-length-scales